# Containerfile entrypoint /bin/sh

Tags: dockerfile, podman

I would like to create a container that runs only one shell. For this I have tried the following:

```
FROM alpine:latest
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh"]
```

Unfortunately I don't get a shell when I start the container.

```
podman build -t $IMAGENAME .
podman run --name foobar $IMAGENAME
podman start -ai foobar
```

But if I start the container as follows it works

```
podman run --name foobar2 -ti $IMAGENAME /bin/sh
/ #

CTRL+C
```

```
podman start -ai foobar2
/ #
```

I had assumed that the entrypoint "/bin/sh" would directly execute a shell that you can work with.

Comment: You need to use the -i flag for interactive.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Containerfile` is fine.

The problem is because your main command is a shell `/bin/sh`, a shell needs a pseudo-TTY or it will fail to start.

You can pass a pseudo-TTY with the `--tty` or `-t` option. Also, a good option is to use `--interactive` or `-i` to allow the main process to receive input.

All the commands below will work for you:

```bash
podman build -t $IMAGENAME .
# run (use CTRL + P + Q to exit)
podman run --name foobar -ti $IMAGENAME
# create + start
podman create --name foobar -ti $IMAGENAME
podman start foobar
```

This is not the case if the main command is something different than a shell like a webserver, as apache, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The entrypoint needs to be a long lasting process. Using `/bin/sh` as the entrypoint, would cause the container to exit as soon as it starts.

Try using:

```
FROM alpine:latest
ENTRYPOINT ["sleep", "9999"]
```

Then you can exec into the container and run your commands.